# Something like a semaphore or lock wait but still process dispatcher queue to prevent deadlock?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, deadlock, dispatcher

I have an Authorizer object which may be accessed from multiple concurrent worker threads.  If the user has recently logged in, it can return an access token immediately.  However it has to dispatch to the UI thread to show a login brower window to the user whenever they need to login again.  While the login method is waiting for the user to log in, other worker threads may request authorization, and it needs to block those until the user is done logging in.  However, since the external call may also have involved the UI thread, blocking external calls also prevents forward progress for the login process, because the UI thread is blocked in the re-entrance.

I can't just use locks (which are re-entrant-per-thread) because dispatching to the UI thread (required for UI element interaction) decouples the relationship between threads and the operation being performed (the thread may change in the process of doing a single "logical" operation, versus many operations all must make use of the same UI thread at times).

Another way of looking at my problem is every time I call Dispatcher.Invoke from the Authorizer to run the UI thread, I have a chance of it being "the wrong" operation that the dispatcher runs (or is running already) before the UI thread loops around to the operation the Authorizer login process needs.  I can't let these other accesses proceed until login is complete, but I can't have my UI thread back until they do complete.

One solution would be to have the "block" actually run the dispatcher queue while it blocks.  Is there anything like this existing already?  If I have to write it from scratch, what is the best way to ask the framework to run other dispatcher tasks while I wait?  Should I just do "while (blocked) { dispatcher.Invoke(() => {/*nothing*/}); }"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle all of this asynchronously, rather than synchronously, as is so often the case in desktop UI programming.

Your `Authorizer` should not block until it can compute the result and return that result, it should instead return a `Task<AuthorizationInformation>` that will allow the caller to be notified of when the result is ready.  The caller of the method, which may or may not be on the UI thread, the needs to add a continuation to that task and then yield up its call chain (to the message loop if it's the UI thread) so as to allow the `Authorizer` to do its thing, and then continue executing through the continuation applied to the task.

The authorize method could look something like this:

```
public class Authorizer
{
    private static Lazy<Task<AuthorizationInformation>> tcsFactory;
    static Authorizer()
    {
        tcsFactory = new Lazy<Task<AuthorizationInformation>>(
            () =>
            {
                var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<AuthorizationInformation>();
                Dispatcher dispatcher = GetDispatcher();
                dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    var login = new LoginWindow();

                    login.ShowDialog();
                    var info = login.LoginInfo;
                    if (info != null)
                        tcs.TrySetResult(info);
                    else
                        tcs.TrySetException(new Exception("Failed to log in."));
                }));
                return tcs.Task;
            });
    }

    public static Task<AuthorizationInformation> Authorize()
    {
        return tcsFactory.Value;
    }

    private static Dispatcher GetDispatcher()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The `Lazy` type is also highly useful for the thread safe "compute this value no more than once, have everyone that requests it be given that value, but don't begin computing it until at least one person asks for it.  This allows us to lazily wait to start computing the value, then when we're ready to start computing it we create a `TaskCompletionSource` to generate a task that we can complete whenever we have a value.  We can then asynchronously requests some work to be done in the UI thread, and then set the result of the task when it finishes.

Comment: Ah.  Something I realized that makes this answer even more helpful is to note it's perfectly fine for the worker threads to choose to block *themselves* (spin wait) on the Authorizer's result; it's just the Authorizer itself who shouldn't block.  The difference between the two is the worker threads are in a position to know they are safe to go into a block, and the Authorizer was not in a position to know.

Comment: @Dennis If they're not running on the UI thread, then sure, they can block on the result of the task.  If they are, then they cannot.  They **absolutely should not** do a spin wait however.  Just call `Wait` or `Result` to do a blocking wait without wasting the CPU's time.

Comment: Right.  I was using "spin wait" as shorthand to describe the intent of "check for a value and wait longer if it isn't there yet", not necessarily to describe how one would literally implement it.  But someone might read that literally, so we should be clear:  In actuality I'd probably use a ManualResetEvent.

Comment: @Dennis No, you should *not* use a MRE.  You shouldn't even check for a value and wait for a period of time if it's not there.  That's a busy wait, which is *also* a really bad idea.  As I said, all you need to do is call `Wait` on the `Task`, or `Result`.  Both will block until the task is completed.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what the TaskContinuationSource class does for a programmer (that couldn't be expressed with just tasks and continuation callbacks), and I think the use of Lazy<T> might be distracting from the clarity of the example. It's unnecessary in my particular case because the lifetime of my Authorizer instance is longer than the worker threads'.  But it seems to me all I need to do is change the signature of my authorize function to "public void Authorize(Action<ServiceAuthorization> continuation)" which would just do TaskFactory.StartNew(() => {block(); continuation();}).

Comment: @Dennis The TCS is a way of creating a task that you manually specify the result of, but that doesn't allocate a thread pool thread at all.  Your solution results in the allocation of a thread pool thread that will just sit there doing nothing for the entirety of it's allocation.  The `Lazy` is important because it means that if this method is called from multiple threads at the same time only *one* window is created, rather than two new windows.  Having the method accept a callback is one option, but `Task` is *far* more powerful and easier to work with, in so many ways.